# Use method from another class, giving error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm attempting to use a method from another class. This question has been asked several times but in my case I get an error. I'm sure this is related to a mistake I've made.

```
class Reports_images extends Reports{
    public function testOG(){
      return('hi there');
    }
}
```

In another file Reports.php:

```
require APPPATH.'/controllers/Reports_images.php';

public function appAddPics_post() {
     $bakerboyTest = new Reports_images();
     $bakerboy = $bakerboyTest->testOG();

     $this->response($bakerboy  ,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

I'm using CodeIgniter with a rest controller everything works except for this. I'm attempting to return a value from a method in another controller.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the exact error message and which line was causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will never work. The Reports_Images class extends the Reports class, at the same time you call the testOG function of the Reports class.

This will work.
Reports_images.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reports_images extends CI_Controller{
    public function testOG(){
      return('hi there');
    }
}
```

Then in other class Reports in Reports.php do this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH.'/controllers/Reports_images.php';

class Reports extends Reports_images{
    public function appAddPics_post() {
       $this->response($this->testOG(), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```